# Take barbecue ashes with me

Tags: fire, cleaning

I do charcoal barbecuing on crown land. When I'm done with barbecuing, I want to take the coals/ashes with me, rather than dump them at the site.

Ashes can be hot and messy to handle, even when doused with water from the nearby creek.

What's a good way to take the ashes home with me in my vehicle?

For example, douse the barbecue and dump the ashes into a lidded, water-tight metal box with water in it. Take the box home with me in the back of my truck and dispose of the ashes at home. *That seems like a reasonable plan, except for the fact I don't know where to get such a box.*

**Edit:**

A couple of options:

- Home Depot or Canadian Tire: [Behrens Galvanized Locking Lid Storage Can, 22L](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/behrens-galvanized-locking-lid-storage-can-22l/1001632693)
- ULine: [Steel pails and lids](https://www.uline.ca/BL_507/Steel-Pails-and-Lids)

Comment: How long between getting the last food of the fire and going home? Or in other words, how hot or cool are they going to be?

Comment: Lots of water-tight metal box options out there. Alu-Box and Zarges are two reasonably well known ones. Not cheap. A steel bucket is pretty cheap.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks. For my notes, ULine in Canada sells steel pails: https://www.uline.ca/BL_507/Steel-Pails-and-Lids

Comment: @Willeke Good question. Hard to quantify. Cooking will have ended 30 mins ago. Coals won't be red-hot, but not cold either.

Comment: A steel bucket, lidded or not, will stand up to hot coals. Pour water to cool appropriately. Use some cover once cold to keep any liquid from sloshing.

Comment: If you doused the coals a steel bucket with plenty of water, your sealed container could be made of anything waterproof because it wouldn't have to handle heat. You do need to make sure they're all fully cold rather than risking damping some and having some still smouldering (fire risk + CO2)

Comment: Congratulations to the OP for packing out the ashes from his fire ring.  Would that more people would do that!  In bear country, the bear canister one packs in filled with food would be suitable for packing out the ashes, if they were wet and no more than warm.

Comment: @ChrisH A smouldering fire would most likely emit CO, something you definitely, absolutely DON'T want in your trunk.

Comment: @pmf yes, I'm not sure why I said CO2 when I meant CO.